# How can I delete a sequence of rows based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have the following dataframe:

```
    id outcome
0    3      no
1    3      no
2    3      no
3    3     yes
4    3      no
5    5      no
6    5      no
7    5     yes
8    5      no
9    5     yes
10   6      no
11   6      no
12   6     yes
13   6      no
14   6      no
```

I want to remove the `no` outcomes at the start of a sequence before a `yes`, and keep all other `no` outcomes, so the output dataframe looks like this:

```
    id outcome
3    3     yes
4    3      no
7    5     yes
8    5      no
9    5     yes
12   6     yes
13   6      no
14   6      no
```

At the moment I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'id': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
       'outcome': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']
     })


df = df[df.groupby('id').outcome.transform(lambda x: x.ne('no'))]
```

However, this simply removes all `no` outcomes.

I know I then need to take the index of these rows and remove them from the dataframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: all the 'no' outcomes before a 'yes', at the start of the sequence per' id'. I also want to know how many of these 'no' before 'yes' at the start of a sequence exists, hence the counting task. Any 'no' after a 'yes' must stay.

Comment: @TSRAI: In your wanted outcome, there is no indication of the number of 'no' that was removed.

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: I found a working answer to your question about keeping the no's at the end of each group. For the question regarding the count of no's at the beginning, I think you should ask a new question for that, because it's a different problem that has to be solved differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to mark all 'no' at the start with a 0:

```
df['no_group'] = df.groupby('id')['outcome'].apply(lambda x: x.eq('yes').cumsum())
```

Now, the number of 'no's to remove is:

```
num_no_to_remove = (df['no_group'] == 0).sum()
```

And the wanted dataframe can be obtained by filtering:

```
df.loc[df['no_group'] > 0].drop(columns=['no_group'])
```

Result:

```
    id  outcome
3    3      yes
4    3       no
7    5      yes
8    5       no
9    5      yes
12   6      yes
13   6       no
14   6       no
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting it too @user17242583

Answer (score 1):

For keeping only last `no` values of each group and all the `yes` values, this code will do the trick:

```py
df = df[(df.replace({'no': np.nan, 'yes': 1}).groupby('id')['outcome'].bfill() != 1) | (df['outcome'] == 'yes')]
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
    id outcome
3    3     yes
4    3      no
5    3      no
8    5     yes
9    5     yes
12   6     yes
```

(In the original `df`, I added a second `no` the end of group `3` to make sure it works for multiple `no`'s at the end).

Essentially what the code does is it

1. Replaces `yes` values with an arbitrary value (`1`) in this case
2. Replaces `no` values with NaN (which is important!)
3. Groups the rows by their ID
4. For each group, replace all NaN rows coming before the last non-NaN row with the value of the last non-NaN row. Since the `yes`'s are `1` and the `no`'s are NaN, this will cause everything **except the last `no`'s of the group** to be replaced with the arbitrary number (`1`)
5. Creates a mask which selects all those last `no` values of each group
6. Creates a second mask which selects all `yes` values
7. Uses those two masks combined to return *, and all `yes` values, and all `no` values that are at the end of a group.*

---

For the question regarding the count of `no`'s at the beginning, I think you should ask a new question for that, because it's a different problem that has to be solved differently.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Apologies, I should have made this clearer. I have updated the question to reflect this. I want to also keep any 'no' outcomes inbetween 'yes'. Basically only removing the 'no' values at the start of a sequence (per id).

Comment: Okay, that shouldn't be too hard. Let me see...

Comment: So you want to remove `no`'s at the beginning of _each group_? But your sample data only has `no`'s at the beginning or end or both of each group, but not _in between_ any `yes`'s in each group.